# How to customize a footer like bootstrap nav-bar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions

I have a scenario where I need to display a footer just like navbar(i.e; need to hide list items of ul list using some button is responsive, on click of that button need to display list items), here I am using bootstrap navbar, but instead of hamburger I need some other customized button. Is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
     </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">list1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">list2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">list3</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: class="icon-bar" is the one that adds Hamburger. Replace it with any other valid html.

Answer (score 0):

From Bootstrap documentation ... You should be able to change the icon here

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

External content
Sometimes you want to use the collapse plugin to trigger hidden content elsewhere on the page. Because our plugin works on the id and data-target matching, that’s easily done!

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="pos-f-t">
  <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-dark p-4">
      <h4 class="text-white">Collapsed content</h4>
      <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  </nav>
</div>
```